# What is xt="SPCLICK" in email template

Tags: html, email, templates

I came across this email template example and on it's button links, there is an attribute xt="SPCLICK".

Can anyone explain that this is?

Thanks!

Comment: no idea - you'd explain which template language is being used.

Answer (score 1):

xt="SPCLICK" is a notation used in SilverPop (Watson Campaign Automation) to indicate a tracked link.